# Responsive Sidebar Tab and Click Event Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, tabs

I have a sidebar that converts to a tab for smaller screen sizes. This is mostly done with css, using JavaScript to open and close the tab. When the tab is open, I've made it so that the user can click anywhere on the screen to close it.

My resize() function will convert the tab back to a sidebar, but, if the user clicked on the tab at the smaller size, then enlarges their browser, clicking anywhere on the screen will make the sidebar disappear.

Basically, all I need to be able to do is to remove the onclick I've set up here, something like

```
if($(window).width() > 751
{
    {remove the event set up in $(document).click(function(e)}
}
```

I've tried using the jQuery ".off" function; stop propagation - nothing seems to work. Even with the right syntax, I'm not sure .off will do the trick, which. I think, may turn off any event clicks which, of course, I don't want to do. Things just need to return to normal when screen size is resized to greater than 751.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#SideTab').click(function()
        {
            // Actual width is 340, allowing for tab (#SideTab) to show
            // Toggle Sidebar open or closed   
            if($('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left') != '-300px')
            {
                $('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left', '-300px');
            }
            else
            {
                // At 0px, Sidebar is showing
                // Event handler allows for Sidebar to close when item on
                // Sidebar is clicked, as well as anywhere outside of
                // Sidebar.
                $('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left', '0px');
                $(document).click(function(e)
                {
                    if(!($(e.target).is("#Sidebar1") || $(e.target).closest("#Sidebar1").length) || $(e.target).is(".cbp-filter-item"))
                    {
                        // Hide Sidebar
                        $('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left', '-300px');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            if($(window).width() > 751)
            {
                $('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left', '0px'); // Show Sidebar
            }
            else
            {
                $('#Sidebar1').css('margin-left', '-300px'); // Hide Sidebar
            }
        }).resize();
    });
</script>
```

Just to reiterate, this code works fine at any screen size. The problem occurs when a user has clicked on the tab at a smaller screen size, then resizes the screen to where the sidebar is active (margin-left: 0). Under those circumstances, clicking anywhere on the screen will make the sidebar disappear. The sidebar should always show when the screen size > 751.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very simple. Don't know why this sat here without 1 response. (Although now it seems, the answer was pretty obvious.)
Simply changed the line

```
if(!($(e.target).is("#Sidebar1") || $(e.target).closest("#Sidebar1").length) || $(e.target).is(".cbp-filter-item"))
```

to

```
if(($(window).width() < 752) && (!($(e.target).is("#Sidebar1") || $(e.target).closest("#Sidebar1").length) || $(e.target).is(".cbp-filter-item")))
```

Comment: Think you need to use stopPropagation? Here's a great article: https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/